# how to use malloc on a pointer correctly?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I have the following struct and tried to use malloc to create a new object dynamically. It seems to work now with **object_ptr obj_ptr1 = malloc(sizeof(object_ptr));** This only assigns the pointer size of object_ptr to obj_ptr1 ? but how do you assign the size of the original struct _object_t in this case?

```
typedef struct
{
   int struct_id;
   void *(*function)(void *);
   int status;
} _object_t;

typedef struct _object_t* object_ptr;

/* create a new object */
object_ptr obj_ptr1 = malloc(sizeof(object_ptr));
```

Comment: you do that by declaring the pointer as a pointer, and by [***not*** casting the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Comment: After your edit: Now it is a pointer, but you are still allocating the wrong size. You are allocating for the size of a pointer to `struct _object_t`. Maybe you should use more telling names, like `struct object_t` and `object_ptr`.

Comment: thanks, I see that the malloc in my question only assigns the size of the object_ptr to obj_ptr1, but how to assign the size of original struct _object_t then?

Comment: @TonyGW Well by writing exactly that `sizeof(_object_t)`.

Comment: @Nabla, can I also write malloc(sizeof(object_ptr*)) ? It's important for me to hide the original structure name. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Typedefs for pointer types are often a bad idea, since they can make it difficult to tell whether a type name refers to a pointer type or not.

Suggestion:

```
typedef struct { /* ... */ } object_t;
object_t *obj1 = malloc(sizeof *obj1);
```

And if you want to allocate space for an array of N objects:

```
object_t *obj1 = malloc(N * sizeof *obj1);
```

Note that I've removed the leading underscore from the type name. Identifiers starting with underscores are reserved to the implementation; you shouldn't define them in your own code.

The `malloc(sizeof *foo)` idiom may take a little getting used to, but it means you don't have to specify the type name more than once, which avoids errors. (The `*obj1` doesn't actually dereference `obj1`, since the operand of `sizeof` is not evaluated.)

In your code:

```
object_t obj1 = malloc(sizeof(object_t));
```

since `object_t` is a pointer type, you're allocating enough memory to hold a pointer object, not a structure object. (Using such similar names `object_t` and `_object_t` for the pointer and struct types, respectively, undoubtedly contributed to the confusion.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your malloc line. You must allocate `sizeof(_object_t)` not `sizeof(object_t)`